# ImportError: No module named 'keras.layers.merge'

Tags: python-3.x, keras, merge, pycharm, importerror

I am trying to import concatenate from keras.layers.merge but getting this error.

I have downgraded keras to 1.1.2. But still facing same error.

The line of code which gives error is:

```
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
```

Also, I can't import Concatenate from keras models against code:

```
from keras.models import Concatenate
```

Comment: can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you please add few lines of error that you are getting.

Answer (score 18):

As @Ivan mentioned, you can use either:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
```

Answer (score 9):

do

```
from keras.layers import Concatenate
```

Comment: By doing so it gives (ImportError: cannot import name 'concatenate'.

Comment: This works for me, you can give a try for `from keras.layers import concatenate`; lower case `c` in `concatenate`

Comment: Now with tensorflow2 you can use either from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate OR import tensorflow as tf and next line from tf.keras.layers import concatenate

Answer (score 0):

In keras version

```
import keras 
print(keras.__version__)
>> 2.12.0
```

Use this

```
from keras.layers.merging import add,concatenate
```